# abi.decode() does not accept "address payable" as type

Tags: solidity, data-types, abiencoderv2, abi.encodewithsignature, decode

```
function myStatic() public returns (uint256[] memory, address payable[] memory, bytes32, string memory) {
    bytes memory encodedResult;
    bool success;
    
    (success, encodedResult) = address(this).staticcall(abi.encodeWithSignature('pickWinners'));
    
    (uint256[] memory wins, address payable[] memory winAddr, bytes32 winnersHash, string memory winnersString) = abi.decode(encodedResult, (uint256[], address payable[], bytes32, string));
    
    return ((wins, winAddr, winnersHash, winnersString));
}
```

I get the error:

```
ParserError: Expected ',' but got 'payable'
   --> contracts/Raffle.sol:357:165:
    |
357 |  ... encodedResult, (uint256[], address payable[], bytes32, string));
```

If, instead, I use `address[]` I get the error:

```
`Type address[] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable[] memory.solidity(9574)`
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a documented way to decode an array `address payable[]` implicitly, however the closest equivalent I can think of is the following:

```
// SPDx-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract Payable_Decoding_Call {
    struct WinnersResult {
        uint256[] wins;
        address payable[] winAddr;
        bytes32 winnersHash;
        string winnersString;
    }
    function myStatic() public returns (uint256[] memory, address payable[] memory, bytes32, string memory) {
        bytes memory encodedResult;
        bool success;
        
        (success, encodedResult) = address(this).staticcall(abi.encodeWithSignature('pickWinners'));
        

        (WinnersResult memory winnersResult) = abi.decode(encodedResult, (WinnersResult));
        
        (uint256[] memory wins, address payable[] memory winAddr, bytes32 winnersHash, string memory winnersString) = (winnersResult.wins, winnersResult.winAddr, winnersResult.winnersHash, winnersResult.winnersString);

    }
}
```